# fetch category details query in magento

Tags: magento

I need a query which displays Category Name,Category url & value of the Custom catgory attribute in Magento
any Guess...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($my_category_id);

echo $category->getName();
echo $category->getUrlKey();
```

Something like this? I am not sure what you mean by custom category attribute and I don't know what a category value is though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id):
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)
    echo $_category->getUrl();
    echo $_category->getName();
    echo $category->getUrlKey();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say your custom attribute is "custom_attribute", then do this:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', 'value_here');
foreach ($categories as $category){
    echo $category->getUrl();
    echo $category->getName();
}
```

Hope this helps.